# How to improve the performance of my Google Script code to avoid a Timeout Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Problem:**

I need to make this script faster because I'm always getting the timeout error.

**Case:**

In Column A I have a set of words that I want to categorise, and in Column B I have the categories, like this:

[List of words in the column A, list of categories in column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Va1.png)

I created a script that does this automatically when I click the button. It only checks the column B empty cells and ignores the ones that have values. Then it checks for the value in the cell to its left, it applies a function with some regex patterns to categorise it, and finally inserts the final category in the empty cell in column B.

My script works fine, but it's super slow and if I have thousands of words it takes more than 6min so I always get the Timeout error message.

How can I make it faster or optimise it so I stop getting the error and my script can work with thousands of words?

**Some considerations:**
This code is a simplified example, my actual script has more categories (about 10), so the time it spends checking the regular expressions is higher.
I tried to do this with formulas in the cells, but it was becoming super crazy, so I made it into a script.

Here is my code:

```
// Variables for Columns
const KW_POS_test = "A";
const CAT_POS_test = "B";
const TAB_test = "test";

// CALL
function showCat_test() {getData_test(CAT_POS_test, cat)};

// SYSTEM FUNCTION
function getData_test(position, dataset) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(TAB_test);
  let currentRange = sheet.getRange(position + "2:" + (position + sheet.getLastRow()));

  currentRange.getValues().map(function(value, index){
    if(value[0].length == 0) {
      let previousCell = sheet.getRange(KW_POS_test + parseInt(index+2)).getValues();
      let currentCell = sheet.getRange(position + parseInt(index+2));
      let result = dataset(previousCell);
      currentCell.setValue(result)
    }
  })
}

// CATEGORY FUNCTIONS

function cat(cell) {
  // Variables for the KW
    var pants = "Pants";
    var tops = "Tops";
    var jackets = "Jackets";  

  // Regex variables
  /* PANTS */   var pantsRegex = /pants|shorts|trousers/i;
  /* TOPS */    var shirtsRegex = /shirt|top|hoodie/i;
  /* JACKETS */ var jacketsRegex = /jacket/i;

   // Statements
    if (pantsRegex.test(cell)) { return pants } else
    if (shirtsRegex.test(cell)) { return tops } else
    if (jacketsRegex.test(cell)) { return jackets }

  }
```

Comment: In order to test your script, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: I added a link to a sheet in the post. I gave commenter rights, I don't know if it's enough. If you need editor please tell me and I'll change. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Yes, it's been solved, but thank you so much anyway, Tanaike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `getValue()` and `setValue()` in a loop, which is very inefficient. It's much recommended to do the following:

- Retrieve the data from your range to a 2D array, using `getValues()`.
- Edit this array according to your preferences.
- Write the edited array to your range using [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

#### Code snippet:

Your `getData_test` could be greatly simplified, like this:

```
function getData_test(position, dataset) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(TAB_test);
  let currentRange = sheet.getRange(KW_POS_test + "2:" + (position + sheet.getLastRow()));
  let currentValues = currentRange.getValues();
  let newValues = currentRange.getValues().map(function(row) {
    return [row[0], row[1].length === 0 ? dataset(row[0]) : row[1]];
  });
  currentRange.setValues(newValues);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Best Practices: Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)